# Reducing PWM voltage peak

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, pwm, voltage-divider

I am putting a late model engine into an older model car and need some help regarding the vehicle speed signal.

The car produces a 12v 50% PWM signal for the speedometer and transmission. The engine management system for the new engine requires the speed signal to be 5v 50% PWM.

Rather than fork out $200 for a brand name signal converter box, I would like to find a simple alternative I can put together myself. I believe using 2 resistors to make a voltage divider would work, but I'm worried that it may have a negative effect on the existing signal.
Can someone please help me out with an easy circuit that won't be taxing on the existing signal?

I'm a mechanic, so my knowledge of creating this type of stuff is minimal. Any help (preferably with a diagram) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you measure the source and "destination" impedance? If the source is low enough and the receiver is high enough, a resistor divider will work fine. Most probably, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Probably doable very simply.
Definitely doable with not TOO much effort.

2 resistors should work OK.
For 12v-5V with no loading by the output, the resistors would be in the ratio 7:5 (7V dropped across the top one, 5V across the bottom for 12V total).
7/5 = 1.4:1
So eg a 1500 Ohm and 1000 ohm (12 to 4V)
or 1500 + 1200 (12 to 5.333v).
Depending on how variable the 12V is and how critical the 5V is such a simple solution may work.

If the output is low resistance it may load Vout down. This can be compensated for by changing resistors. A zener diode "clamp" on the output keeps the Vout more constant and provides a degree of protection against over-voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWUOSO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the 12V may be eg 11-14V and/or the %v must be 5 +/- 0.1V or ... then more precise solutions are not much more complex. If you have a better guide to voltage ranges and if you can provide vehicle and equipment model/brand details it may help.

Safer methods which better isolate the 12V from the 5v circuits can be designed if desired.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a scope pattern of the 12v signal (not sure how to upload it) It shows 12v +/- 0.2v. I think +/- 0.2v range on the output side would be also acceptable. Would putting the signal through a resistor distort the signal in any way? And does the resistance of the resistor make a difference, even if the pair are still in the same ratio, example if the resistance is higher or lower than the ones you mentioned but the ratio is the same?

Comment: @Luke If you input 12V +/- 0.2V for a perfect resistor ratio and no loading you'll get 5V +/- (0.2 x 5/12) V or about +/- 0.1V. The resistor tolerances and nominal values used will modify the actual Vout. Depending on the design of the EMS the signal input may be highish impedance (lightish load) or reasonably low impedance (heavier load). The latter may be used to minimise noise affects but I'd expect higher impedance to be more likely. I purposefully specified lower than perhaps usual resistor values (ie around 1k (1000 Ohms range) rather than 10k or higher ...

Comment: ... in an attempt to 'swamp' likely loading levels. It's possible but not likely that the drive has limited current capacity and the 1k is too low. Unlikely in an automotive system but possible. 
If the EMS input is significantly capacitive then signals will increasingly tend towards looking like curved sawtooths with increasing resistance but, again, the values around 1k should not have this happen unless they have done something unusual. If needed a simple "active drive" can be added (transistor or cheap IC) but very unlikely to be needed. ||For interest - where are you located? I'm in NZ.

Comment: A divider of e.g. 1k and 680 + 33 gets 12V down just a tiny shade under 5V with E12 values, handy to know if you don't care about using one more resistor.

Comment: Thanks @RussellMcMahon, I'll give it a try tomorrow if I get time. I have a breadboard and a bunch of resistors to play around with, and a scope at work I can use. Would I be best to include the zener diode too? I may also try what replete said with adding another resistor. I'm located in Australia.

Comment: @Luke **IF** the 12V source is of low variation and **IF** 5.0V is what is really wanted then aiming at 5.0V may be good. In practice resistor tolerances, source variation, target supply voltage variation and actual target acceptable Vin range may make it safer to err slightly on the low side. It may not matter, and it may. The zener has the advantage if allowing you to set a nominally slightly too high Vin, allowing for variations as above, and then to use the zener to clamp it. Zeners are usually specified at an operating current of 10 mA ...

Comment: ... (maybe 1 mA, maybe other) so Vzener will be < 4.7V at low clamping current. With 1K Rupper I will be about (12V-7V)/1k = 7 mA. This all flows into Rlower if the values are ideal. 
If Voutactual is high the zener starts to take up any extra. A 5V1 zener is probably OK as it will be at < 5V1 up to about 10 mA zener current. Which to use depends on the actual tolerance of the EMS target. An eg 1/4 Watt zener is very low cost and provides some protection of your $200 EMS.  ...

Comment: ... | If desired a TL431 "shunt regulator" / active-zener with 2 resistors can clamp V_EMS_in to within about 1% of target and actual value can be varied by resistors used. TL431 is under $1.

Comment: I tried the 2 resistor divider method yesterday which was a fail. My input is a 12v square wave but when I joined the divider into the circuit my input dropped down to around 6-7v square wave,  and the output was even lower at around 3v. I didn't get a chance to try anything else. Should I use higher value resistors or would I be better off isolating the 2 signals?

Comment: @Luke As I noted - the values depend on input drive capability and output loading. Vin dropping to say 6V implies the source was about the same impedance as the 2 resistors in series or about 1.5k. Increasing the resistors by a factor of 10 would probably load the Vim minimally (about 1 Volt). Whether the EMS also loads the output is tbd. It MAY be that the EMS would work on ~= 3V.  It is likely that the loading as now will not damage the source BUT it may. Try with resistors 10x s high, measure Vout and then if < 5V see how much the EMS loads it.